# Uninstall livecode

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall

I'm new to linux/ gnu and running in lots of problems and find that answers are rather difficult to come by.
Currently on Kubuntu 22.04 I want to uninstall livecode as I don't have enough time to learn lc programming but it has set itself up as the default program for quite a number of file types so that when not paying attention and clicking on some file I wish to open with Kate instead livecode comes up. Pretty annoying. So I ran:

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove livecode`

but the system answered me:

```
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto livecode
```

which in English means that livecode could not be found (And brings up another topic for me which is why the ... my system/ konsole/ bash answers in Italian and displays man pages in German.
This (that the system could not find livecode) is, I guess, due to the fact that I installed livecode with the livecode installer and not with apt get. I did try to run the installer again to see if there was an uninstall option, but at least I could not find such option.